# IT Hit CalDAV / CardDAV server user permission settings

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Regards: IT HIT CalDAV / CardDAV server.

It seems when opening the IT HIT Ajax File Browser the logged in user can see all content off all users.
How can we set permission so a user can only see his own content?

Comment: Maybe this topic will resolev your problem ? - http://davical-general.89287.n3.nabble.com/Davical-general-CardDAV-permissions-td4008965.html

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the folder content in [IItemCollection.GetChildren](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.IItemCollection.GetChildren.html) method implementation. This method returns list of child items in a folder. Depending on user permissions you can filter items visible for the loged-in user.

The sample CalDAV/CardDAV server and sample code generated by IT Hit CalDAV/CardDAV Server Wizard contain GetChildren method in DavFolder class implementation in DavFolder.cs.

Note that in case you store data in Windows file system and rely on Windows file system permissions, all users always see the same folder content regardless of their permissions on sub-folders and files. This is how Windows file system permissions work. So there is no simple way to filter visible folder content only manipulating file system permissions. (Users however can not for example navigate to subfolders or open files if they do not have enough permissions)